# UICollectionView in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use a UICollectionView inside a UIViewcontroller and having some issues...not sure what I am doing wrong? I set the UICOllectionView in the storyboards to dataSource and delegate but am still getting errors...Thanks for any and all help!

```
class AlbumViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let collectionViewA = UICollectionView()
    let collectionViewAIdentifier = "AlbumCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initialize the collection views, set the desired frames

        collectionViewA.delegate = self
        collectionViewA.dataSource = self


        self.view.addSubview(collectionViewA)



    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewA {
            let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(collectionViewAIdentifier) as UICollectionViewCell

            // Set up cell
            return cellA
        }



        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if collectionView == self.collectionViewA {
                return 0 // Replace with count of your data for collectionViewA
            }

            return 0 // Replace with count of your data for collectionViewB
        }


    }
```

Comment: And still getting errors. What kind of errors? Print them here. Muku already has mentioned about registering cell in viewdidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in `viewdidLoad`

```
collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("YourCellClass"),forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CELL");
```